# how to solve :Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries

Tags: hibernate, named-query

I have a named query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Notification.findByyoungngAndInstNum",
        query = "SELECT n FROM Notification n WHERE n.institutionsregister.institutionnumber = ?1 and n.young is not null and n.date is null")
```

I want to add an extra check where I want to add the age of young >=25 yrs

I tried this

```
SELECT n FROM Notification n WHERE n.institutionsregister.institutionnumber = ?1 and n.young is not null and age(current_date, n.young.dob) >= (interval '25' year)) and n.date is null
```

but getting the error while deploying in jboss.(Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries)

The table names are:
Notification ,
Institutionregister it has the field institutionnumber ,
Young table has the field dob(date of birth).

not able to figure out how to frame it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate solution , try this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -25);
      Date dt =  calendar.getTime(); // use this as query argument, it can be dynamic


  SELECT n FROM Notification n WHERE n.institutionsregister.institutionnumber = ?1 and n.young is not null and n.date is null and n.young.dob < = ?2
```